# How to apply not filter in shopify rest api?

Tags: shopify, shopify-app

I'm using Shopify API to get all the products. **GET /admin/products.json**. Found that i can apply filters only to `title, vendor, handle, product type, collection ID`.

In order to get all the products which has `'aaa' as vendor` and `'bbb' as product type`. I have applied it as, **`GET /admin/products.json?vendor=aaa&product_type=bbb`**.

No i need to get all the products which `DONT have vendor 'aaa'`. I have tried with `!=` operator. It haven't worked for me. Can you please help me on this?

Answer (score 0):

You can run queries like that using [the new admin GraphQL API.](https://www.shopify.ca/partners/blog/graphql-admin-api)

```
POST /admin/api/graphql.json HTTP/1.1
X-Shopify-Access-Token: [your-token]
Content-Type: application/graphql

query {
  products(first:50, query: "NOT vendor:aaa") {
    edges {
      node {
        id
        title
        vendor
      }
    }
  }
}
```